# Python как сделать многопоточный прокси чекер?

Tags: python

У меня есть однопоточный прокси чекер, цель сделать его многопоточным. Я думаю как это реализовать. Способ разделить список прокси на кол-во списков = кол-во потоков не подходит, т.к. если один поток закончит раньше другого работу то он просто не поможет своему брату. Вот и думаю как правильно организовать многопоточность.

Comment: Используйте очереди https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160417/threading-queue-working-example  Но учитывая, что проверка прокси 99% времени находится в  ожидании ответа по сети, более эффективным будет использование асинхронности (см. asyncio) вместо многопоточности

Comment: Но так то можно и через Pool.imap например, очень просто вообще

Comment: Решение от Mike мне помогло