# Как сделать цикл асинхронным?

Tags: python, asyncio

Я пишу API сервис по валидации прокси.

Сама валидация происходит в отдельном потоке, однако, предварительно список прокси сортируется, проверяется на наличие в базе данных и т.д.

Все это происходит в цикле `for`. Этот подготовительный этап генерирует большое количество метаданных, доступ к которым необходим раньше, чем завершится изолированный процесс проверки.

Проблема заключается в том, что такой подход может создавать длительные блокировки.

Отсюда появляется идея сделать цикл асинхронным, однако я не совсем понимаю, как именно это реализовать.

```
async for i in proxy_list: ...
```

В конечном счете я бы хотел получить простой итератор `for`, но без глобальной блокировки.

Comment: асинхронность не избавляет от gil

Comment: Нужно смотреть как у вас proxy_list генерируется. Вот этот этап и нужно изменить так, чтобы он отдавал данные по мере генерации, а не накапливал все, потом полные результат отдавал.

Comment: дубликаты-дубликаты. [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1305679/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1313142/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1405825/178576), и т.д. и т.п.